# How to jump from flutter_web page to the outside web link?

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to use flutter to develop a web site. Now I need to jump from my web page to a link outside the station. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import `import 'dart:js' as js;` and then you can open a link like the following example:

```
. . .
onPressed: () {
            js.context.callMethod("open", ["https://google.com"]);
},
. . .
```